# Org's Capture: annoying duplicated date tree outlines

Tags: org-mode

*(Environment: Emacs 24.4 stable with built-in org-mode.)*

I want to have a `file+datetree` for Org-mode's Capture, so I set like this:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("D" "Diary + Timer" entry
         (file+datetree (concat org-directory "/diary/diary.org"))
         "* %^{Description: } %^g  \n  %i %?\n" :clock-in t :clock-keep t)
        ("d" "Diary" entry
         (file+datetree (concat org-directory "/diary/diary.org"))
         "* %? %U")
        ))
```

And use these captures to add items for `diary.org` several times. I expect the file has:

```
* 2014   
** 2014-11 11 月
*** 2014-11-21 金曜日
**** test1 [2014-11-21 金 03:08]
**** test2 [2014-11-21 金 03:08]
**** test3 [2014-11-21 金 03:08]
```

But what I get is like this:

```
* 2014
** 2014-11 11 月
*** 2014-11-21 金曜日
**** test1 [2014-11-21 金 03:08]
** 2014-11 11 月
*** 2014-11-21 金曜日
**** test2 [2014-11-21 金 03:09]
** 2014-11 11 月
*** 2014-11-21 金曜日
**** test3 [2014-11-21 金 03:09]
```

How to solve this problem...? (I've ever used Org's Capture one year ago, and it worked just liked I wish; I have no idea why it becomes this.)

---

[Edited] Finally, totally out of expect, the problem is resulted from Pangu-Spacing....
https://github.com/coldnew/pangu-spacing/issues/5

Comment: Maybe the regexp org is using to find an existing line is failing to match for some reason? Does a regexp search work for e.g. `"^\\*+[  ]+2014-\\([01][0-9]\\) \\w+$"` (which I derived to match month headers from org-datetree.el).

Comment: Seems it will not match because your month line has an extra 'word'. Looking at the org source I don't quite see why you're getting "2014-11 11 ..." on the month line, but that will never be matched so a new month line will always get added.

Comment: With your config, my month line is created as `** 2014-11 November`, which matches the regexp above. So the issue seems to be the month name being formatted to `11 月`.

Comment: I doesn't touch any language-related settings within Emacs; the time string format is from system. (By the way, in somehow elder version Org-mode 8.x, this function seemed to be able to work correctly, because I just found some my old diary archives.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be a mismatch with how org-datetree is creating the month line and the regexp it uses when you create a second entry for the same month.

On my machine (with my locale etc) the current month line is generated as:

```
** 2014-11 November
```

Org is using a regular expression like this one to match the line when I create a new entry:

```
"^\\*+[     ]+2014-\\([01][0-9]\\) \\w+$"
```

This matches properly for me. In your example, it looks like the month name is written as two "words" rather than one:

```
** 2014-11 11 月
```

Therefore the regular expression will never match, and org-datetree will create a new month line every time.

Org-datetree is generating the month name using:

```
(format " %s" 
    (format-time-string
     "%B" (encode-time 0 0 0 1 11 2014)))
```

where `%B` means to use the current locale's full name for the month. Not matching your locale's default representation of the month seems like a bug in Org mode.

To work around it you either need to figure out how to change that locale representation, or perhaps hack your org-datetree.el to fix the regexp to match an additional word (in `org-datetree-find-month-create`, e.g. `\\w+ \\w+$`). You might also be able to use 'after' advice on `org-datetree-insert-line` to revise the month line after it is written.

Comment: Well, maybe it's time to report bug to Org-devel... :S